# Getting a contract by address only (without ABI definition)

Tags: web3js

Is it possible to get a contract only by its address without the ABI definition?

I'm experimenting with ethereum in a private network through the `web3.js` client console.

The problem is that any error in node will cause the client to crash. I was careful enough to store the contract address, but not the ABI definition.

Is there a good approach for solving this problem?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-do-you-get-a-json-file-abi-from-a-known-contract-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the source code, just recompile it. It will give you the same ABI.

Comment: @Péter Szilágyi Could I get the abi  only by the address that the contract stored?