# Convert contract arguments to ABI-encoded format

Tags: cpp-ethereum, abi

My Contract Source
https://gist.github.com/munggo/ed25afb0aff9169a6c57f1d464d13177

Convert contract arguments to ABI-encoded format
How???

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3149/16048 ?

Comment: Thank you.
But can you give me a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to compile your contract using Remix. Its the solidity web based compiler.  It is super handy.  It will give you that ABI that you need for your contract. It will also give you some the Web3.js info that you need.  I would do some research on remix - its a great tool.

https://remix.ethereum.org/

Comment: Thank you.
But can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: Copy and past your smart contract in to Remix.  After it compiles click the button to the right of the screen that is called "Details".  This will give you the bytecode, ABI   and web3 Deployment information