# Can I get abi file from deployed contract? or resore abi json file

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, abi, truffle-deployment

I deployed ERC-721 contract to mainnet last night with truffle

Contract is successfully deployed

but no abi file generated (I don't know why..) so I can't run my dapp

https://etherscan.io/address/0x5bd8e480270880ff2c02c7b30610d6823eb1748a

Here is my contract on etherscan

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd4f11c140f6a7bb308a714158bc5f229fda0d8c5705be42c5d8b98015b9afd28

and transaction

I already paid 0.4 ETH for gas fee, ran out of my balance

I can't run migrate --reset again...

I have sol file and abis file with testnet so

Can i restore my mainnet abi json file? or Get abi file from etherscan Bytecode contract?

++ Already try https://etherscan.io/apis#contracts but failed "Contract source code not verified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the abi json file is like an interface for the user to call so it is universal. So you can just use remix ide and compile the sol file contract and get the abi json from there. It will be the same as the abi json on the blockchain

Tl;dr:
[How do you get a json file (ABI) from a known contract address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-do-you-get-a-json-file-abi-from-a-known-contract-address?rq=1)

Comment: Thx friend I never use remix IDE but i understand what did you mean. I just made mainnet abi file from testnet abi file. thank you.