# How can I call a function from a deployed smart contract on ethereum?

Tags: nft

I'm a junior blockchain developer, I deployed a smart contract on Ethereum blockchain for NFT collection. How can I call **reveal** function to reveal NFTS using remix or ethers js ?

```
function reveal() public onlyOwner {
        revealed = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JavaScript with ethers.js, you can do this:

```
import yourDeployedContract from '../build/contracts/yourDeployedContract.json'
import {ethers} from 'ethers'
import Web3Modal from "web3modal"

async callReveal() {
    // Get ethereum provider with Web3Modal
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    // Get contract data on the network you deployed your contract on
    const network = await provider.getNetwork()
    const contractData = yourDeployedContract.networks[network.chainId]

    // Get smart contract
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractData.address, yourDeployedContract.abi, signer);

    // Call reveal method
    let revealTransaction = await contract.reveal();

    // Wait for transaction to be complete 
    await voteTransaction.wait();

    // Rest of the code here
}
```

*yourDeployedContract.json* is the JSON file generated when you called "truffle migrate".

Comment: That's was so helpful thank you, Benjamin. what is I want to interact with a contract than not mine deployed on etherscan.io that has only ABI and address? how can I get the JSON file ? Can I interact with it in the same way?

Comment: Yes you can, here's how to do just that: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-do-you-get-a-json-file-abi-from-a-known-contract-address.