# Retrieving contracts from contract address

Tags: web3js

I am trying the sample voting contract given in the Solidity docs
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html.

I managed to deploy the voting contract to the blockchain.

Once the contract is deployed, how do I access the different methods of the contract later from web3?

The functionality I need is:

- new user signs up to a service
- address of this new user should get added to the list of voters using the giveRightToVote method in the contract
- After a fixed time,all the voters should cast their votes using the vote method
- Get the results of the voting using winningProposal method

How do I achieve this functionality using just the contract address in web3?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!  And have you read these sections: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Comment: Or do you mean http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/getting-a-contract-by-address-only-without-abi-definition ?

Comment: sorry! hadn't read the docs properly! got it working using contract.at(address)