# Web3.js Get Contract Abi Knowing Only Contract Address

Tags: contract-development, web3js, javascript, abi

is there a way with web3.js to get a contract abi json, knowing only the contract address?

I cannot find anymore a link in wich they explain how to do this, in this post the guy replied telling that there is a way to do this but it's not so well documented.

How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting a contract by address only (without ABI definition)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/getting-a-contract-by-address-only-without-abi-definition?rq=1) and [How do you get a json file (ABI) from a known contract address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-do-you-get-a-json-file-abi-from-a-known-contract-address?rq=1)

Comment: This will be possible for contracts that register their metadata in Swarm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**a) you know the source code of smart-contract**

programmatically: see the link to gist from Ivan's answer

manually: with [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org)

**b) you don't know the source code but smart-contract was verified in one of the explorers**

Then, use block explorer search to get ABI of smart-contract. For example, you can read the verified source code of smart-contracts in [BlockScout](https://blockscout.com), [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io), [Etherchain](https://www.etherchain.org)

**c) you don't know the source code && contract is not verified**

You can use [Panoramix smart-contracts decompiler](https://eveem.org/api/) to get a partial ABI of smart-contract

Answer (score 5):

To add to o0ragman0o's comment, see this doc:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/metadata.html

It outlines how contract metadata should be published to Swarm to avoid centralized (i.e. Etherscan) management/access to contract metadata (including ABI).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question before. For now is not possible, only you can do it with solc compile.
Here is an example : 
https://gist.github.com/tomconte/4edb83cf505f1e7faf172b9252fff9bf

Answer (score 0):

you can always solc then call the abi from a file or directly.
source : [Solcjs](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js)